# SerializeToCodedStream to serialize msg and parse it using ParseFromCodedStream. The parsed result is inconsistent with the content of msg

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I use `SerializeToCodedStream` to serialize msg and parse it using `ParseFromCodedStream`. The parsed result is inconsistent with the content of `msg`. Please help me find the reason.

Below is my code:

```
class CNetStream    : public CBufferStream ,public ::google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream
{
private:
    bool        m_bHaveNext;
public:
    explicit CNetStream(char* pBuffer, uint32 uSize);
    explicit CNetStream();

protected:
    virtual bool    Next(void** data, int* size);
    virtual void    BackUp(int count);
    virtual bool    Skip(int count);
    virtual ::google::protobuf::int64   ByteCount() const;
public:
    inline  bool    ParseFromStream(::google::protobuf::Message& msg)
    {
        ::google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream in( (const ::google::protobuf::uint8*)getSpareBuffer(),getSpareSize());
        return msg.ParseFromCodedStream(&in);
    }

    inline  bool    SerializeToStream(const ::google::protobuf::Message& msg)
    {
        m_bHaveNext = true;
        ::google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream out(this);
        if ( !msg.SerializeToCodedStream(&out) )
            return false;

        return skipPosition( out.ByteCount() );
    }
};


PBCASShuangXiuIntimacySend ask;
ask.set_npcid(npcid);
ask.set_itemid(itemid);
ask.set_itemcnt(itemCnt);

CLog::warn("CClientGMCommand::shuangXiuIntimacySend ask[%s]", ask.ShortDebugString().c_str());

uint8 uEventID = 0;
CNetStream clStream;
clStream.SerializeToStream(ask);

PBCASShuangXiuIntimacySend ack;
CHECKF(clStream.ParseFromStream(ack));
```

The parsed result is:

[image]